# Tuple error in PIL.Image.paste when actually using a Tuple

Tags: python, osx-mavericks, python-imaging-library

This error is a bit tricky, because the code I'm using runs on my other systems no problem. I installed the libraries on a fresh machine today and ran into errors trying to run my code (that works on other OSX 10.9 machines).

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "proofer.py", line 295, in <module>
    main()
  File "proofer.py", line 286, in main
    save_target = composite1(proof1)
  File "proofer.py", line 170, in composite1
    blank_canvas.paste(proof.sized, (paste_width, paste_height))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 1103, in paste
    self.im.paste(im, box)
SystemError: new style getargs format but argument is not a tuple
```

The code it's referencing is below

```
blank_canvas.paste(proof.sized, (paste_width, paste_height))
```

proof.sized is a PIL.Image object, as you can see below:

```
proof.sized=proof.image.resize(tuple([int(des_xx), int(des_yy)]), Image.BICUBIC)
```

It seems like my error message is incorrect in this case, as the problem isn't the tuple-ness of my 2nd argument to im.paste(). From the research I've done it seems a number of people are receiving this feedback regardless of what their problem actually is.

So... what am I missing here? This code runs on my other systems fine. How can I figure this out?

Comment: Are you using PIL or Pillow?

Comment: @MattDMo Sorry - I'm pretty sure I'm using PIL. 

`from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont, ImageCms`

Comment: @user2666063: Pillow is a repackaging; it contains the same module. You'd use `from PIL import ...` with Pillow as well.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I'm pretty sure it's PIL - I installed it direct from source here: http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/

Comment: Yes, then it's PIL you are using. :-)

Comment: to find out which one you're using, open the interactive Python prompt and run `import PIL`, then `dir(PIL)`. If it's Pillow, you'll see a constant listed named `PILLOW_VERSION`. If it's PIL, you'll just see `VERSION` (among a few other things, of course)

Comment: `Python 2.7.5 (default, Aug 25 2013, 00:04:04) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.0 (clang-500.0.68)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import PIL
>>> dir(PIL)
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__']
>>>`

Answer (score 0):

Try installing [`Pillow`](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) (`sudo pip install Pillow`) and re-running your code. Development of PIL stopped at version 1.1.7. Pillow is a fork of PIL (currently at version 2.3.0), including all of the original functions, but with many improvements as well. It's likely that if this is a bug in PIL, it has been addressed in Pillow.

Comment: I did this!`>>> import PIL
>>> dir(PIL)
['PILLOW_VERSION', 'VERSION', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '_plugins']
>>> ` however, I still get the same bug!

`    self.im.paste(im, box)
SystemError: new style getargs format but argument is not a tuple`

Comment: @user2666063 - no, don't uninstall PIL, because they share some of the same files. You could try going into your `site-packages` directory and deleting the `PIL` directory, the `PIL...egg-info` file, and the `Pillow....egg-info` directory, then installing Pillow again, just to make sure you don't have any left-over `.pyc` or `.pyo` files that may be causing issues.

Comment: Ok - it's a client computer so I'm not on-site anymore. Thanks for the guidance and I'll be sure to get back to you in a few days. I think you are spot on, because my local machines have PILLOW installed so that's probably why it runs.